# rotate text labels with VegaLite in Observable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation, observable, vega-lite

I can't find a way to rotate the text labels for the "Name" labels up top. I am working in Observable notebook. Here is the code:

```
vegalite({
  width: 50,
  data: { values: StackVega },
  mark: 'bar',
  encoding: {
    column: {
      field: "new_name",
      type: "nominal",
      spacing: 2,
      title: "Name"
      // rotate:
    },
    y: {
      type: "quantitative",
      aggregate: "sum",
      field: "new_rate",
      title: "Rate",
      axis: { grid: false }
    },
    x: { type: "nominal", field: "stat", axis: { title: "" } },
    color: {
      type: "nominal",
      field: "stat",
      scale: { range: ["#675193", "#ca8861"] }
    }
  },
  config: {
    view: { stroke: "transparent" },
    axis: { domainWidth: 1 }
  }
})
```

I have tried to add `axis: { labelAngle: -50 }` but that didn't do anything.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the `column` encoding, you need to use `header: {labelAngle: -50}`.

See [Header](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/header.html) for more information.

Here is an example adapted from https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/bar_grouped ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICONjgaC17WVJnyAvkszaksiADM22hGgDaoNzSCmHDa+qqYDAiUAJ5wSNoABAC8SQkATAAMWSAOoFBIglDmanBhapGUEHAAHsmpaQkA-AkA5ABiiAVwLQmorQCyXS2KIEgQ+mRwssohOQC6SgDuNMr0aKAQwThoAIxpDiDI2gDW+kzxI1NQbMo0smTrINeCkfKaIAFwgsr6SJMjmGiOFK6E8t1kBRGEBwSCgdweqB2GSU8CQM1C7wsTC+AEF7oIQfwxABWOwHaKPP5kbR8YL6CCREafb76YGmAkAugc9AmMwWTBWEZIao0cbvakrNBuApVMlKaqPZk-dCTaazJTC0WPAWYbkgHIHZ6eRU0L7KkCq9FQ-Lc0DOe4gnwgADEADYAOzEnYATgAzCNnfkABxB107EBzMmGuQBBGgYimxaPTbaNjHEEgJwuaHxKaYHIakVi0DKNjIO4AdRWa0RUaAA)):

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it just shifted the names to the left, instead of making them appear at the angle...

Comment: I updated the answer with a demonstration of this. If it's not working for you, that is a bug, and it would be worth reporting to the Vega-Lite issue tracker with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It looks like this was recently fixed: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7150